# How can I hide Label using code

Tags: c#, .net

I am unable to hide label using C# code.

How I can possibly hide the label through coding in c#?

please help me.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? ASP.Net, WinForm, WPF etc ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried it because the label1.visibility=false; showing incorrect syntax.

Comment: @user3300068: its not visibility. it is `Visible` !!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Control.Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

`label.Visible=false;`

If win-form you can use [Control.Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)